# Printer settings change depending on wether I execute my app from Visual Studio or from IIS

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, zebra-printers

I have an application developed with Visual Studio 2015 that exposes web services and one of them takes care of print a label with a barcode through a Zebra printer.

This printer is connected in the local net and in my Windows 10 is installed properly. And I configured the size of the paper to be 10x10cm.

If I debug my code through VS2015 and I call my web service, the label is printed with the size I configured.

Now, the problem comes when I publish my application to IIS and I try to call the web service. The label is printed but with smaller size (I think this size comes by default in the printer). After some time researching, my deduction is that printer settings are stored linked to my windows user, but IIS is using another printer settings and I don't know why.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,

Joan

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you use visual studio debug to run your application, it will use the current login user as the account name.

If you host the applicaion on IIS, it will use application pool identity account to run your application.

The account name is IIS `AppPool\YouIISsitename`.

I suggest you could try to add setting to this account.